# Proper way to write CSS elements/divisions?

Tags: css, html, menu, html-lists

I'm learning CSS and was just wondering which way is best when writing CSS:

`div.divname`   or   `.divname`

`ul#menu`   or  `#menu ul`

etc etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a difference between every element you've specified.

`div.divname`
Will match all *divisions* with the class name 'divname'.

`.divname`
Will match all *elements* (divisions, paragraphs, anchors, everything) with class name 'divname'.

`ul#menu`
Will match the unordered list that has the ID 'menu'.

`#menu ul`
Will match the unordered list that is contained *within the element* with the ID 'menu'.

Other than explaining these, I don't know exactly what you're trying to do. All I can recommend is avoid specifying class names that can match to any element as much as possible, and remember that only one element can have a specific ID inside a single document. From the first example, `div.divname` would be better. From the second example, they are both completely different.

Comment: Thank you! That makes complete sense now :)